# Perl LWP: Send Cookie by HTTP header not work

Tags: perl, cookies, lwp

I have known that if you want to use cookie, you must write code as:

```
$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$ua->cookie_jar(HTTP::Cookies->new());
```

then you can get(), post() and so on.

But if I just put the cookie string into the HTTP HEADER and get(), I can not get the correct response. As:

```
$ua = LWP::UserAgent->new();
$ua->get($url, 'Cookie' => $cookie_string);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you will find that the `Cookie` header is being set correctly using that method.

To make sure, you can write

```
my $resp = $ua->get('http://www.myurl.com', Cookie => 'my=data');

print $resp->request->as_string;
```

and you should see that the request contains the line

```
Cookie: my=data
```

Answer (score -1):

From the docs, it looks like `$ua->cookie_jar()` expects a hash, either to specify options or to provide a data structure to store the cookies in.  I would try

```
$ua->cookie_jar({});
```

Also, be aware that the method you are trying to use will only store cookies in memory, so once your script ends, so does your knowledge of said cookies.  You may want to look at

[http://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::Cookies](http://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP%3a%3aCookies)

http://www.perl.com/pub/2002/08/20/perlandlwp.html

For examples of both in-memory cookie jars, and file-based ones.

As to why HTTP::Cookie wouldn't return a suitable hash when called they way you did, I'm not sure but it appears that it isn't.

Comment: The `cookie_jar` method expects an object as its parameter. You would normally pass an instance of `HTTP::Cookies`, but any object that provides the necessary methods will do. As a short cut you can pass an empty anonymous hash, when `LWP::UserAgent` will create an `HTTP::Cookies` object for you. What the OP seems to want is to pass a specific `Cookie` header in the request.